# How do you fix an Apple Hardware Test (AHT) configuration?

Tags: snow-leopard, apple-hardware-test

I have two MacBookPros on which I run 10.6.8. One has a Core i5 (MacBookPro6,1), the other a Core i7 (MacBookPro8,3). I move the SSD from one to other as occasion or whim demands. On the Core i5, AHT runs successfully. On the Core i7, AHT fails to launch. Before the machine shuts down, it briefly displays a window with the error: “Apple Hardware Test had trouble reading env file Configs\AHT_default.env”.

Where is this file located? (note the "\" in the file name). How do I repair it?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! I've offered an answer below, but if you're sure you're using the correct versions of AHT let me know and we'll go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Apple Hardware Test to work, you need to ensure you're using the correct version for the model of Mac you're testing.

Assuming you have the model identifiers correct:

- the MacBookPro6,1 is a Mid 2010 17" MacBook Pro which uses **AHT 3A175**
- the MacBookPro8,3 is a Early 2011 17" MacBook Pro which used **AHT 3A211**

My guess is that you're trying to run the same version of Apple Hardware Test (AHT) on both machines, and this is where you're running into problems.

**[UPDATE]**

Below are direct links to download each of the above versions of AHT directly from Apple:

- [AHT 3A175](http://download.info.apple.com/Apple_Hardware_Test/022-4596-A.dmg)
- [AHT 3A211](http://download.info.apple.com/Apple_Hardware_Test/022-5054-A.dmg)

You can run AHT from a bootable USB drive, but first you will need to copy the AHT onto your USB drive and bless it so it can boot your MBP.

Comment: The version I installed was from the install disks that came with the MacBookPro8,3 — the machine that gives the error about not finding AHT_defaults.env. I'll check the version.

Comment: The version I installed was from the install disks that came with the MacBookPro8,3 — the machine that gives the error about not finding AHT_defaults.env. I'll check the version. I neglected to mention that AHT used to run on the MacBookPro8,3. That was _before_ I discovered the now replaced SSD had so many bad sectors TimeMachine was unable to perform a full backup. (I'm actually still trying to recover from that...you really don't want to know...)

Comment: I dug further into the AHT installer package from the Applications Install Disc. I discovered the package installs 25(!) versions of apple_hardware_test.acm. One version contained 3A175 in the bundle id string. None included 3A211. I'm inferring two things: 1) I don't have the right version of AHT for the MacBookPro8,3; 2) I don't know which machine the 10.6.4 installer DVDs accompanied.

Comment: I can help you with that. The 10.6.4 installer DVDs would have accompanied the mid 2010 model MBP. To expand on that further, the mid 2010 models initially shipped with 10.6.3 and later with 10.6.4. The mid 2011 models initially shipped with 10.6.6 and later with 10.6.7.

Comment: And I agree, you'd have the wrong AHT for the MacBookPro8,3 (Early 2011) model which needs AHT 3A211, which is what I was getting at with my answer. At least now we know which AHT you have and which one you don't, so you're further down the track.

Comment: I've just updated my answer to add direct download links to both versions of AHT (not that you need both, since you've found one). If you need help in how to set AHT up so you can boot it from a USB flash drive, let me know.

Comment: Thank you! I also found an excellent resource for AHT on GitHub:  [AppleHardwareTest](https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest). The page provides a nice summary of the steps to create a bootable image.